UI freeze when I press on the toolbar button
why in my home view the UI freeze after I press few times on one of the menu buttons.
nothing special on my home, is quite simple, can't find what is wrong.
Sometime after one press sometime after few times but after a while ui freeze just simple pressing on the menu buttons.

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

enum stateMode  {
    case deleteMode
    case updateMode
    case normalMode
}

struct Home: View {
    @ObservedObject var netManager: NetworkingManager
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
            return [
                GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center),
                GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center),
                GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center)
            ]
        } else {
            return [
                GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center),
                GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center)
            ]
        }
    }
    @State var openAddPlayList = false
    @Query var playListBackground : [PlayListModel] = []
    
    @State private var mode: stateMode = .normalMode
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    LinearGradient(colors: [.color1, .color2, .color3], startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .topTrailing)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    if playListBackground.isEmpty {
                        Spacer()
                        ContentUnavailableView("Please Insert a new Playlist", systemImage: "display.and.arrow.down")
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    else {
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                                ForEach(playListBackground) { playlist in
                                    PlaylistItemView(playlist: playlist, columns: columns, readerWidth: reader.size.width, mode: mode)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Playlists")
//                .navigationBarTitleTextColor(.white)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup {
                        Menu {
                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation {
                                    mode = .deleteMode
                                }
                            }) {
                                Label("Delete Mode", systemImage: "trash.circle.fill")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation {
                                    mode = .updateMode
                                }
                            }) {
                                Label("Update Mode", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// Define the PlaylistItemView
struct PlaylistItemView: View {
    let playlist: PlayListModel
    let columns: [GridItem]
    let readerWidth: CGFloat
    let mode: stateMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch mode {
        case .normalMode:
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "tv")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
                Text(playlist.playlistName)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: readerWidth / CGFloat(columns.count) - 20, height: 150)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
        case .deleteMode:
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
                Text(playlist.playlistName)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: readerWidth / CGFloat(columns.count) - 20, height: 150)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
        case .updateMode:
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
                Text(playlist.playlistName)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: readerWidth / CGFloat(columns.count) - 20, height: 150)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
       
    }
}



I believe the issue is being caused by the re-renders and heavy computing in the body.
struct PlaylistItemView: View {
    let playlist: PlayListModel
    let columns: [GridItem]
    let readerWidth: CGFloat
    let mode: stateMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if mode ==.normalMode {
                Image(systemName: "tv")
            } else if mode ==.deleteMode {
                Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
            }
           .resizable()
           .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
           .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
           .padding()
            Text(playlist.playlistName)
               .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
       .frame(width: readerWidth / CGFloat(columns.count) - 20, height: 150)
       .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
       .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

Instead of doing recursive calls try doing it in a single vstack which should resolve your issue.
